# Smarty sort array

Tags: php, smarty

Im looking to sort a list of product names being output by Smarty. Here is the current code:

```
{foreach from=$products key=i item=product}
  <li>
      <a href="discuss.php?product={$product.uri}
      {if $filter_style}&amp;style={$filter_style}{/if}">{$product.name|capitalize}
      </a>
  </li>
{/foreach}
```

The HTML output:

```
<li>zzzzz</li>
<li>qqqqq</li>
<li>ccccc</li>
<li>aaaaa</li>
```

How can I sort A-Z?

Comment: Sort it inside PHP. Even if the possibility is there, you should avoid using "complex" data manipulation inside smarty.

Comment: can u use php and sort 
before looping 
sort($products) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is possible but this is not the perfect solution:

```
{php}
   sort($this->_tpl_vars['your_smarty_variable_name']);
{/php}
{foreach...
```

If you want to do it anyway in smarty it would be much easier (and elegant) to write a smarty plugin.

btw. the {php} {/php}tags in smarty 3 are deprecated

Comment: in case you missed it, the moral of the story is to not use Smarty. Use PHP as the templating engine it was designed to be. (Just be sure to separate your logic and view into different files.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this inside the template rather than in the PHP which assigns the array, you can write a custom modifier for the array which sorts it in the foreach loop. See [this blog post](http://smartcoding.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/smarty-sort-array/) for an example